# Ruby on Rails - The account renewal function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to create the function about the account renewal. If the account will expired at 2015/11/20, it only have seven days to renewal or it will be changed to the inactive account. how could I do with cancancan and devise gem or another way to archive that? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be based on scheduling:

- Each day, the scheduler will pull each account which "expires" on that day
- With the returned accounts, it will put them into a queue (probably on Redis)
- Another task cycles through the queue every day, until the day of expiry - when the account is removed from the queue and made "inactive"

---

To do it, you'd need to have an `active` attribute in your `Account` model, so that you can define whether it should be treated as active or not. You will also require an `expires_at` attribute, to determine its expiry date.

You'd then use something like [ResQue](https://github.com/resque/resque) to manage the queue (it uses [Redis](http://redis.io)), and you'd use a Rake Task to pull the required data.

--

## Lookup

Firstly, you will have to create a *scheduler*.

This will be done at OS-level (it has to invoke a Rails function on request).

If you're using Heroku, you'll be able to use the [`Heroku Scheduler`](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler) plugin, which is Heroku's wrapper for a *cron job*.

Alternatively, you could also use a cron job if you're running unmanaged / shared hosting.

You can [read about cron jobs here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron):

> The software utility Cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems. People who set up and maintain software environments use cron to schedule jobs (commands or shell scripts) to run periodically at fixed times, dates, or intervals.

You should set up a cron job to run `rake` from the cmd (Cron is basically a smart way to call the cmd/bash - allowing you to run commands from it).

Thus, you'd use something [like this](https://askubuntu.com/a/2369):

```
0 0 * * * rake accounts:activate
```

--

## Rake

This would have to be backed up with a `rake` task (which lives in `lib/tasks/your_rake_task.rb`:

```
#app/models/account.rb
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :expires_tday, -> { where("expires_at = ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day) }
end

#lib/tasks/account_activator.rake
namespace :accounts do
  desc "Find expired accounts & put them into queue"
  task :activate => :environment do
      accounts = Account.expires_tday
      accounts.each do |account|
         $redis.add(account.id, account.expires_at) #-> will have to set up redis
      end
  end

  task :expire => :environment do
      /// look up accounts in redis and assign them as "expired"
  end
end
```

This should take a daily snapshot of your soon-to-be expiring accounts, sending them to the `Redis` queue, which you can then process using a similar setup:

--

## Redis

Redis is a semi-persistent data store, kind of like RAM for your app.

You're able to add `key:value` pairs to a Redis instance, allowing you to use it for queues etc.

I would personally send the soon-to-be expired accounts to a Redis install, allowing me to then perform another `cron` each day to assign the account as `expired` on the day it expires:

```
0 0 * * * rake accounts:expire
```

This could also be achieved with [`Resque`](https://github.com/resque/resque)

Answer (score -1):

Cancancan is for abilities while devise is for authentication.

What you want to do however is a constant look at your users, to see who is active, who will soon expire, and perform some operations on the status of the user.

If this is correct, what you should be looking at is running a cron job (i.e. a daily recurring job) which will be tasked to go through your users at a specific time each day to fetch users that fall in a specific status, and perform whatever operation you want on those.

There are several resources that could help you achieve this. You can find information on that [from the ruby toolbox here.](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/scheduling)

These includes:

- Whenever
- Rufus scheduler
- Resque scheduler
- Clockwork
- Craken
- Taskit
- Recurrent

Each of these has documentation on how to implement it.

Hope this was helpful...